# PySpark filter works incorrectly with one True built using lambda funtion

Tags: pyspark, lambda, where-clause, boolean-logic

I was debugging a function and I have encountered a misterious thing:

Given a PySpark dataframe with one column (name_id) I build another (is_number) one using a lambda function to see if name_id is a string whose characters are numbers.

The resulting dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
df.show(4, False)
```

| name_id | is_number |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | true |
| 0002 | true |
| 0003 | true |
| 0004 | true |

I need to count the number of True values, so I do the following:

```
df.where(F.col("is_number")==True).count()
```

3

Three?? Really? What is happening here?

It gets stranger:

```
df.groupBy("is_number").count().show(4, False)
```

| is_number | count |
| --- | --- |
| true | 4 |

It looks like all True values are the same, BUT:

```
df.groupBy("is_number").count().where(F.col("is_number")=="True").collect()[0]["count"])
```

3

Again, it looks like applying the where function eliminates one True value. The filter function works the same.

Additionally I have detected which True value is the one excluded, and it is the first one.

```
df.where(F.col("is_number")==True).show(4, False)
```

| name_id | is_number |
| --- | --- |
| 0002 | true |
| 0003 | true |
| 0004 | true |

Other things I have tried: Expressing True as not False doesn't work. "true" values shown are True representations, not a string "true". Using EqNullSafe() instead of == doesn't work.

Any ideas? This is a complete nonsense for me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you do `printSchema()` of `df`?

Comment: root
 |-- name_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_number: boolean (nullable = true)

Comment: Update: It works if I do df=df.cache(). This is not optimal, since it might raise errors with large dataframes.

Comment: Update: It works with PySpark 3.1, but not with PySpark 2.4.